# Error at line 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, compiler-errors, oracle-apex

So, i have this trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER COD_MEMBER

BEFORE INSERT ON members

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

 member_id number;

BEGIN

 SELECT seq_member.nextval

  INTO member_id

  FROM dual;

:new.n_member := member_id;

END;
```

/​

I am new with this stuff so i´m not sure if i am doing this right.

The error is: Error at line 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I have this table for members:

```
DROP TABLE members CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE members (

n_member NUMBER(9),

name_level VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

email VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

date_birth DATE NOT NULL,

date_ins DATE NOT NULL,

date_end DATE NOT NULL,

phone_number NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,

name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(n_member),

FOREIGN KEY(name_level) REFERENCES level_member(name_member));
```

I hope you guys can help me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that sequence object `seq_member` doesnt exists.

If you use SQL*PLus ot SQLcl or SQL Developer you can use `show errors` command to view full error stack on last on your SQL.